# Strange url when using PJAX and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link like `http://www.test.com/testë` where there is special character ; `ë`.

In my browser's address bar, it shows like: `http://www.test.com/testÃ«`

How to manage that bad encoding using [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) library?

What I have:

```
$.pjax ({
   container: $("#main"),
   timeout: 1000,
   replace: true
});
```

I have tried using `encodeURI(url)` and `decodeURI(url)`, but it didn't workout, still replace URL by PJAX.

I saw that:

```
obj.url = stripPjaxParam(xhr.getResponseHeader('X-PJAX-URL') || options.requestUrl)  // line 672 from jquery.pjax.js
```

causes problem. How to fix it ?

Comment: Can you try adding `charset="utf-8"` to the `script` tag of `pjax` library and also to the script where you are doing the request?

Comment: The scripts tag are rendered in ASP.NET MVC (using BundleConfig)

Comment: let's try another think.. add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` into the `head` tag.. maybe it solves the issue..

Comment: I already have meta ... but still is a problem. I see that from `jquery.pjax.js`, see my updated question

Comment: That's not valid URI `http://www.test.com/testë` regarding spec: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2

Comment: So, what's the solution ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes Is that your own URL or pointing to external link you cannot change?

Comment: So why not setting it as: `http://www.test.com/teste`? Or you could still use url rewriting server side to make `http://www.test.com/testë` pointing to `http://www.test.com/teste` if e.g `testë` is some kind of variable dynamically handled server side. That's said, e.g wiki is using often special character in their URLs so it could have other way but i guess it is browser's behaviour dependants. I can see some links on wiki correctly showing special chars on chrome and FF but not on IE where they are escaped